# How can I add ui-router stateProvider configuration to my application with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Before when not using Typescript I was adding my ui-router state information like this:

```
app.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    '$sceProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    appConfig
]);

function appConfig(
    $httpProvider, 
    $locationProvider,
    $sceProvider,
    $stateProvider
    ) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);

    var admin = {
        name: 'admin',
        url: '/admin',
        views: {
...
        }
    };
```

Now I am using Typescript I assume I should code this into a class.  But how can I add the class to my app? I already have this code where I added a controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
    ])
    .controller('appController', AppController);
```

I tried to add the state information as a .config but it appears this only accepts a function as the argument.

Can someone tell me how I can add my state information for ui-router to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't gain an advantage from using a class here because you don't need to use `this` or add properties to it in the `config` function. Just use a function like its JavaScript (TypeScript won't complain).

Answer (score 18):

This is the way I am defining the `ui-router` states .. in typescript *(as other parts are in TS...)*:

```
module MyModule
{
    export class MyConfig
    {
        constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider
            , private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider   
            ... // other dependencies)
        {
            this.init();
        }
        private init(): void
        {
            this.$stateProvider.state("App", <ng.ui.IState>
            {
                abstract: true,
                .... // more settings
            });

            // more states
        }
    }
}

angular.module('MyModule')
  .config(
    ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", // more dependencies
        ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) =>
        {
            return new MyModule.MyConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider);
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree there is no advantage by using a class. However you can use TypeScript for the config and have type definitions (intellisense + compile time checking), no need to use javascript directly either.

I have the app configuration and the ui-router configuration in the same file `app.config.ts`

```
((): void => {
    'use scripts';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = [
        '$locationProvider',
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider'
    ];

    function config($locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider,
        $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {

        //html5 removes the need for # in URL
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        //angular-ui-router for multiple views
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', <ng.ui.IState>{
                url: "/",
                views: {
                    "viewA": {
                        templateUrl: "app/home/homenav.html"
                    },
                    "viewB": {
                        templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
                    }
                }
            });
            //more states here.
    }
})();
```